# Export contacts through API

Tags: java, exchange-server-2010

Has anyone got any idea how to export contacts of an Exchange Server 2010 mailbox to a Java-application?
Preferably in Java, or even better in a SOAP-based XML exchange, we're looking for a web-based solution anyway.

Kind regards,
Gerard

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd877045%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx)?  There's even source code for a [Java API](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi).

Comment: Yeah, I've found http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Exchange-2013-Retrieve-fb5baa8b and am installing Visual Studio 2010 at this moment. But I'm new to this stuff and was looking for some hands-on advice.